# Can Scripts host on openshift connect remote mysql?

Tags: openshift

I have a php script host on openshift, how it connect to my own mysql database on my vps which allow remote connection ? thank

Answer (score 0):

You probably want port forwarding. See this page for more info: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift